# Exercise 4.4, Mathematical Analysis 2nd ed. - Apostol

Tags: sequences-and-series

Two sequences of positive integers $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are defined recursively by taking $a_1=b_1=1$ and equating rational and irrational parts in the following equation

$$a_n+\sqrt2\,b_n=(a_{n-1}+\sqrt2\,b_{n-1})^2\qquad \text{for}\,n\geq2$$

The first question of the exercise asks to prove that

$$a_n^2-2b_n^2=1 \qquad \text{for}\,n\geq2$$

Can someone give me a hint so that I can start working following a right path? I cannot interpret the problem. What should I see?

Expanding the square and subtracting $2\sqrt2b_n$ from both sides I get

$$a_n-\sqrt2b_n=a_{n-1}^2+2b_{n-1}^2+2\sqrt2a_{n-1}b_{n-1}-2\sqrt2b_n$$

I cannot see the perfect square on the RHS.

Thank you.

Comment: A simple path is to identify $a_n$ and $b_n$ by expanding the square on the RHS, then to note that these expressions imply that $a_n-\sqrt2 b_n=(a_{n-1}-\sqrt2 b_{n-1})^2$ and finally to deduce $a_n^2-2b_n^2$ in terms of $a_{n-1}^2-2b_{n-1}^2$.

Comment: @Did I edited my question, I tried to expand the RHS even before posting the question. But I cannot see the $(a_{n-1}-\sqrt2b_{n-1})^2$. Why? I am sure I am missing something trivial...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** Expand to get $a_n =a_{n-1}^2 +2b_{n-1}^2$, and $b_n =2a_{n-1}b_{n-1}$.

Now, using the above can you prove that $c_n=a_n^2 -2b_n^2$ is constant for $n\geq 2$ ?

Comment: Could you tell me what's wrong in my expansion of the RHS? Why I cannot obtain the same results you obtain?

Comment: @Charlie expand : $$a_n+b_n\sqrt{2} =a_{n-1}^2+2b_{n-1}^2+2a_{n-1}b_{n-1} \sqrt{2} $$ Since $a_n,b_n$ are integers we can identify them directly. 

To prove what "Did" told you, use $b_n=2a_{n-1}b_{n-1}$ in you RHS in the expansion.